# export linq query to a text file

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, text

I want to make a text file from a linq query.
The point is that my query produces more than **3000 records each time** and when I use **foreach** it takes 2 minutes to extract all records and fields data.

```
foreach (var query3 in query)
{
    line += (string)query3.Name.Trim() +"\t"+(string)query3.Code.Trim()+"\n";
}
```

**How can I export linq query to a text file or string variable??**
my query is something like :

```
var Query=from c in db.Exp select c;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to save the results into a text file?

Comment: Why is query time relevant to writing to a text file?

Comment: What takes two minutes, to select 3000 records? How long does this take in SSMS: `SELECT * FROM Exp`? Maybe you should show your code. I'm pretty sure that we'll find the reason for the issue there. I reckon that your query will be executed in the `foreach` loop on every iteration.

Comment: i added foreach code to the post

Comment: Is line of type String?

Comment: yes, line's type is String

Comment: Who is query3? What object type object is?

Comment: Just noticed, why isn't q2 used in the loop?

Comment: sorry query3 was right q2 is wrong i changed it too

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use string when you perform a lot of string appending. Since string is an immutable object, a new block of memory is allocated in each iteration. You should use StringBuilder instead:

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var q2 in query)
{
    line.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\n", query3.Name.Trim(), query3.Code.Trim());
}
File.WriteAllText(@"...", line.ToString());
```

Comment: Even better, open a `FileStream` and use a `StreamWriter` to write the data to the file. This way you don't keep using more memory by adding data into the `StringBuilder`, and instead you write each line to the file immediately.